# Detect metamask installation without refreshing page

Tags: browser, metamask

I'm struggling with detecting that my user has installed metamask extension while being on my page. I have install button which redirects user to the metamask page, if he installs it the window.ethereum is not being updated without refreshing the page.

Is there another way of detecting that metamask was installed?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is metamask library for this https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-onboarding